# How to extract the extension from a filename in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am looking for a simple way to extract the extension (.txt, .py, .jl, etc) from a file in Julia. I looked through the [Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/) but didn't see anything specifically built for this.

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Comment: It absolutely is. People get so upset about that sometimes, but it really is very much in line with the goals of the site as a whole.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `splitext` from [Filesystem](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.splitext)

```
julia> splitext("/home/myuser/example.jl") 
("/home/myuser/example", ".jl") 

julia> splitext("/home/myuser/example") 
("/home/myuser/example", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a faster alternative, if that is of any importance:

```
file_extension(file::String) = file[findlast(==('.'), file)+1:end]
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is no built in Julia function to do this, what you can do is given the filename, split the string on a period "." as follows:

```
julia> filePath = "some/path/my_program.jl"
"some/path/my_program.jl"

julia> split(filePath, ".")[2]
"jl"
```

Comment: I would use `split(filePath, ".")[end]` to be sure to get the file extension..

Comment: This fails when there are dots in the file path. `end` is indeed the best solution.